Equation in svg does not look the same as in MathJax equation
I'm trying to write a program that produces an svg file displaying math equations. For example, I want this equation in an svg file . The font in this equation is the one used on EE.SE (MathJax). The javascript code I intend to use is:
const fs = require('fs');

const svgTemplate = `
<svg width="400" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <foreignObject x="10" y="10" width="380" height="80">
    <math class="math" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
      <mrow>
        <msub><mi>V</mi><mtext>in</mtext></msub>
        <mo>=</mo>
        <mi>cos</mi>
        <mo stretchy="false">(</mo>
        <mi>&#x03C9;</mi>
        <mo>&#x2217;</mo>
        <mi>t</mi>
        <mo stretchy="false">)</mo>
      </mrow>
    </math>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
`;
fs.writeFileSync('equation.svg', svgTemplate, 'utf8');

console.log('SVG file created successfully.');

It generates an svg file containing this equation:  while I wanted . There is a difference in the font.
How can I make the font the same as the one used in MathJax?

The font differs because the MathML is being processed by the browser's MathML implementation rather than by MathJax.  It might be possible to use CSS to style the MathML using MathJax's v2 fonts, but I'm not sure.
The fact that you are wrapping MathML inside an SVG seems strange.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Since this will only work in a setting where the browser already knows how to render MathML, by not just use the MathML directly?  With the SVG wrapper, you will need to determine the height and width attributes, as well as a vertical-align offset CSS style to get the baseline positioned correctly (see how the images in our post are not sized or positioned properly).  Note that these values may be browser dependent (they will depend on the browser-specific MathML implementations and the fonts in use for that browser), so you are likely to get this wrong for some situations.  This seems to be a very fragile approach.
If it is that you need to have the math in an image format, why not use MathJax to produce the SVG itself?  Then you will have the needed fonts (and the height, width, and vertical-align will already be computed for you).  You could use one of the mml2svg implementations in the MathJax node demos repository, for example, to do this.
